# What does it mean for localization to be same if multiplicative set is different? $T^{-1}R = S^{-1}R$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

If R is a ring and p is a prime ideal, I was told that somehow $Frac(R/p)$ was the localisation $(R \setminus p)^{-1}R/p$. I thought it was more like the localisation $(R/p \setminus\{p\})^{-1}R/p$ but apparently these are the same. But why? What exactly should I verify? (I am new to all this localization business).
Also, in general what does it mean for $T^{-1}R$ and $S^{-1}R$ to be the same if $T$ and $S$ are different?

Comment: I guess they are isomorphic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe $(R\setminus p)^{-1}(R/p)$ is confusing since $R\setminus p$ is not a subset of $R/p$? It would indeed be better to write $(\overline{R\setminus p})^{-1}(R/p)$, where the overline means taking classes modulo $p$. Alternatively, the latter can be written as $((R/p)\setminus\{\bar 0\})^{-1}(R/p)$ which coïncides with your suggestion.

Your question as to when two localizations $T^{-1}R$ and $S^{-1}R$ are isomorphic is a nice exercise: let $\tilde S$ be the *saturation* of a multiplicative subset $S$ of $R$ defined by
$$
\tilde S=\{r\in R\mid \exists t\in R\colon rt\in S\}.
$$
In words, $\tilde S$ is the subset of all divisors of the elements of $S$.

One can prove that $\tilde S$ is again multiplicative and that the natural morphism from $S^{-1}R$ to $\tilde S^{-1} R$ is an isomorphism. Also, $\tilde S$ is exactly the subset of elements of $R$ whose image in $S^{-1}R$ is invertible. With that in hand, it is easy to prove that the localizations $S^{-1}R$ and $T^{-1}R$ are isomorphic if and only if $\tilde S=\tilde T$. One has to note that by isomorphism of localizations I mean here that there is an isomorphism between $S^{-1}R$ and $T^{-1}R$ that is the identity on the image of $R$. Without that precision, it may well be that the rings $S^{-1}R$ and $T^{-1}R$ are abstractly isomorphic without $\tilde S=\tilde T$. An example of the latter are the rings $\mathbf Z[X,Y]_X$ and $\mathbf Z[X,Y]_Y$, where $R_r$ denotes the localization of the ring $R$ with respect to the multiplicative subset $\{1,r,r^2,\ldots\}$.

Comment: It is not too confusing that $R \setminus p$ is not a subset since this is a localisation of modules where $R/p$ is seen as an R-module. But why can you just take the classes module p and say it is the same as $(R \setminus p)^{-1}(R/p)$?

Comment: OK, I didn't get it that you thought of $R/p$ as an $R$-module. There are, indeed, two localizations of $R/p$: the localization of $R/p$ as an $R$-module by $R\setminus p$, and the localization of the ring $R/p$ by its multiplicative subset $(R/p)\setminus\{0\}$. It is clear that there is a map from the former into the latter. This map is an isomorphism of $R$-modules.

Comment: Is the morphism $\frac{[r]_p}{t} \mapsto \frac{[r]_p}{[t]_p}$? Why is it enough to show that if $t-\hat{t} \in p$ then $\frac{[r]_p}{t}-\frac{[r]_p}{\hat{t}}$

Comment: Yes, that is the morphism. I don't understand your second question.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say : Why is it enough to show that "if $t-\hat{t} \in p$ then $\frac{[r]_p}{t}=\frac{[r]_p}{\hat{t}}$" to show that it is an isomorphism? Is this even true?

Comment: I did not say that that was enough to prove; just follow the definitions: surjectivity of the map from $(R\setminus p)^{-1}R/p$ to $(R/p\setminus\{0\})^{-1}R/p$ is clear. As for injectivity, it suffices to prove that the kernel is trivial. Suppose that $\frac rt=0$ in $(R/p\setminus\{0\})^{-1}R/p$. This means that there is $s\in R\setminus p$ such that $sr=0$ in $R/p$. Hence, $sr\in p$ and $r\in p$ since $s\not\in p$. This implies that $\frac rt=0$ in $(R\setminus p)^{-1}R/p$, and proves injectivity.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! I got confused for a moment.